# Select or browse for multiple folders in gwt

Tags: gwt

I have a requirement where I need to select multiple files or folders using the Browse button in GWT. This is the code snippet that I am trying. I can do a multiple file selection but it doesn't work for a single folder selection.

```
public MultiFileSelection( Element element )

{

   super( element );

   element.setAttribute( "multiple", "multiple" ); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

   element.setAttribute( "webkitdirectory", "" ); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

   element.setAttribute( "directory", "" ); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

}
```

This works for multiple file selection but I cannot achieve a folder selection and my final aim to is to achieve multiple file or folder selection through the same Browse button.

Comment: Please add more info, what do you call the GWT browse button ?

Comment: What I mean is the Browse button rendered in the browser through gwt.

Comment: I are talking about input type ? Like this : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_file  I am not sure your pb is GWT related